# capture mouse events in a kaggle notebook

Tags: events, mouse

I want to loop through an array of images
in a kaggle jupyter notebook used the mouse scroll wheel.

I copied like crazy from many places.

One thing worked in a jupyter notebook
%matplotlib notebook

This would not work in kaggle
complaining that it could not find IPython

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is the function I'm trying to get working in a Kaggle note book

Comment: This is the function I'm trying to get working in a Kaggle note book

class IndexTracker(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, X):

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

tracker = IndexTracker(ax, y)



fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', tracker.onscroll)
plt.show()

Event not seen

Answer (score 0):

```
# I think this can be extended to handle mouse events
# https://www.kaggle.com/code/maevaralafi/diving-into-ipython-widgets
import ipywidgets as widgets

# For explicitly displaying widgets
from IPython.display import display

# Just need these for the demo purposes here
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create an simple IntSlider widget
demo_IntSlider_1 = widgets.IntSlider(
    min=1,                      # The minimum value
    max=100,                    # The maximum value
    description='Int Slider 1', # Label 
    value=53,                   # Default value
 )
```

## Display the widget

```
display(demo_IntSlider_1)
```